# C++ best practice - function type alias std::function<T> or T

Tags: c++

What is considered to be best or good practice when declaring type aliases for function types in C++ (I know this part of the question is probably subjective)? Either

```
using FuncType = void(int, int);
```

or

```
using FuncType = std::function<void(int, int)>;
```

Are there benefits of one over the other?

How should I use these types as function arguments (when passing as functor, lambda, member or global function), for example

```
void foo(FuncType&& func) { ... }
void foo(FuncType func) { ... }
void foo(std::function<FuncType> func) { ... }
```

**EDIT**

I know that not all of my examples above are applicable with both #1 and #2 but that is not the point. I want to know which (and why) option is better and how should I pass this type when using it as a function argument.

## Specific use case

As it appears to be too broad (which I absolutely understand) I'm going to give more detail about my specific case.

I have a class that holds a vector of functions that I want to call (most likely parallel, but I don't think this matters). In this class I can add functions to the vector at runtime.

For example:

class

```
Container
{
public:
    using FuncType = std::function<void(const SomeComplexDataType&, int, double)>;

    inline void addFunction(FuncType func)
    {
        _funcs.push_back(func);
    }

    inline void call(const SomeComplexDataType& a, int b, double c)
    {
        for (auto& func : _funcs)
            func(a, b, c);
    }

private:
    std::vector<FuncType> _funcs{};
};

struct HeavyFunctor
{
    // contains some heavy objects    

    void operator()(const SomeComplexDataType& a, int b, double c)
    {
        /* Some heavy workload */
    }
};

int main()
{
    Container c;    
    c.addFunction([](const SomeComplexDataType& a, int b, double c) { /* do something lightweight */ });
    c.addFunction(HeavyFunctor);
    c.call(x, y, z);

    return 0;
}
```

How should I define `FuncType` and the parameter for `addFunction` and how can I store them in the vector (in a best case scenario, without copying the callables)?

Comment: Only the first option works with all three of your examples...

Comment: Use a template parameter directly if you want to write such function. `std::function` has significant overhead.

Comment: Second is not an alias for a function type at all. It is an alias for a template class specialization.

Comment: I've updated the question to clarify it a bit. @VTT You are right, but I think it's clear what I'm asking. I just don't know how to rephrase it.

Comment: This question is too broad and partially opinion-based - No one can say which one is better, there are too many places where one could be better than the other, plus you are leaving away many alternatives (template parameter, function views, etc.).

Comment: The thing is these are not alternatives. Like chair and table - both are furniture but are used differently.

Comment: @Holt I will update my question to be more specific about my use case. I never heard of function views. Do you have any references for further information about that topic?

Comment: Timo, see my article on the subject: https://vittorioromeo.info/index/blog/passing_functions_to_functions.html

Comment: @VittorioRomeo Very nice article. The part about function view gave me some good insights. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

I'd personnaly use:

```
typedef std::function<void(int,int)> FuncType;
```

and

```
void foo(const FuncType &func) { ... }
```

edit:
Not the best for performance considering comment on this post as it requires virtual dispatch.

Comment: *"easy of user and performance"* - You won't get performance with this 1) `std::function` needs virtual-dispatch for its call operator, which may add (significant) overhead if you need to call the function frequently and 2) you are copying `func`, which may contains a heavy-to-copy functor, which may not be necessary if you don't plan to store `func`